# issue with inout parameter in procedure

Tags: vhdl

I am writing a bus functional model for a testbench, I am using a procedure to handle the read and write operations, ideally i would like to use one bus declared as an inout.

I am using a record type to instantiate my bus, but when i declare it as an inout parameter in my procedure call it appears to work for signals that are outputs from the procedure, but does not recognize inputs into the procedure. Any signal inputs are uninitialized "U". I know for synthesis this method does not work, but for a testbench i thought it was possible to instantiate a bus as an inout.

My record type and procedure are instantiated as follows:

```
type t_apbp_intf is record
    -- APB-pipe Interface
    paddr   : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    psel    : std_logic;
    penable : std_logic;
    pwrite  : std_logic;
    pwdata  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    pstrb   : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    prdata  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    pready  : std_logic;
    pslverr : std_logic;
    prdvld  : std_logic;
end record t_apbp_intf;

procedure nai_bus_cyc(
    wr_rd_n          : in    std_logic;
    addr_in          : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- Address
    data_in          : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- Data to be written
    signal tb_m_apbp : inout t_apbp_intf) is
begin
    if wr_rd_n = C_BUS_WR then
        wait until rising_edge(tb_clk);
        tb_m_apbp.paddr   <= addr_in;
        tb_m_apbp.psel    <= '1';
        tb_m_apbp.penable <= '1';
        tb_m_apbp.pwrite  <= '1';
        tb_m_apbp.pwdata  <= data_in;
        tb_m_apbp.pstrb   <= "1111";
        wait until rising_edge(tb_clk) and (tb_m_apbp.pready = '1');
        tb_m_apbp.paddr   <= (others => '0');
        tb_m_apbp.psel    <= '0';
        tb_m_apbp.penable <= '0';
        tb_m_apbp.pwrite  <= '0';
        tb_m_apbp.pwdata  <= (others => '0');
        tb_m_apbp.pstrb   <= "0000";
    else
        wait until rising_edge(tb_clk);
        tb_m_apbp.paddr   <= addr_in;
        tb_m_apbp.psel    <= '1';
        tb_m_apbp.penable <= '1';
        tb_m_apbp.pwrite  <= '0';
        tb_m_apbp.pwdata  <= (others => '0');
        tb_m_apbp.pstrb   <= "0000";
        wait until rising_edge(tb_clk) and (tb_sprvalid_bus = '1');
        tb_m_apbp.paddr   <= (others => '0');
        tb_m_apbp.psel    <= '0';
        tb_m_apbp.penable <= '0';
        tb_m_apbp.pwrite  <= '0';
        tb_m_apbp.pwdata  <= (others => '0');
        tb_m_apbp.pstrb   <= "0000";
    end if;
end procedure;
```

Comment: Your question doesn't provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the problem can't be demonstrated with the snippet you present. If you aren't driving record elements out on your mode inout signal the driver will have a default value of 'U' which will resolve  to a 'U'.  In your procedure  assign the elements you are not driving to a 'Z' which resolves to the value of a second driver. You'd want to do the same to the record signal if you drive elements externally and the procedure call is concurrent.  You can simply initialize to 'Z'.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.4.2.3 Signal declarations, para 10 *If a subelement of a resolved signal of composite type has a driver in a given process, then every scalar subelement of that signal shall have a driver in the same process, and the collection of all of those drivers taken together constitute one source of the signal.* A concurrent procedure will elaborate to a process statement. (11.4 Concurrent procedure call statements *A concurrent procedure call statement represents a process containing the corresponding sequential procedure call statement.*

Comment: 5. Types, 5.1 General para 10 *The term subelement is used in this standard in place of the term element to indicate either an element, or an element of another element or subelement. Where other subelements are excluded, the term element is used instead.*